# Excel | Sheets: Display numbers between range in one cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

This may be rather simple though having a hard time finding the correct way to do it.

I work with Vehicle fitment quite a bit so we have a lot of year ranges displayed as `1997-2000`.

Though in our web data sets they need to be displayed as `1997,1998,1999,2000,etc.`, which I have just been entering manually. The ranges tend to be quite high such as `2000-2019` so it has become quite meticulous.

My questions is there a way to display the numbers in between a given range in one cell separated by a comma or given delimiter.

```
A = 1998  B = 2000  c = 1998,1999,2000,
```

```
|    A    |    b    |        c        |
   1998      2000     1998,1999,2000,
```

### **ANSWER EDIT**

Thank you @Gary's Student! I wanted to post an edit I made for my application.

Our catalog usually states years as `YYYY-YYYY` though sometimes we say `2018+`. So I added a `=split` and `=IF` statement to clean up my sheet of `#REF` haha.

T2= `2000-2006` U2= `=SPLIT(T2,"-")` V2= `"populated by U2 formula"` W2= `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(V2),T2,(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDIRECT(U2 & ":" & V2)))))`

with U2 populating V2 when left blank it will display U. In my case that would always be a year displayed as YYYY+

**NOTE:** This is in google sheets

[image: formula spreadsheet screen cap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With values in **A1** and **B1**, use the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ROW(INDIRECT(A1 & ":" & B1)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 2):

Just because google sheets was also tagged, here's how you'd do it there:

```
=ArrayFormula(textjoin(",",true,row(index(A:A,A1):index(A:A,B1))))
```